# CSS - THEAD cutting out on subsequent pages

Tags: html, css, laravel

[image: Print Preview - pg1 left / pg2 right]

Hi Guys,
Having an issue where thead is getting cut on pg2+ when printing.
I have tried everything and its still "cutting".
Adding a @page {margin-top:16cm;} simply makes it start half way, but still cut.
Ive added an image of the print preview to show what is going on (confidential information has been blurred out)

CSS Code:

```
/* Reports */
.kt-reports{
    border-top-left-radius:4px;
    border-top-right-radius:4px
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__container{
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 30px
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__head{
    border-top-left-radius:4px;
    border-top-right-radius:4px;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding:80px 0 20px 0;
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__head .kt-reports__container{
    border-top-left-radius:4px;
    border-top-right-radius:4px
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__head .kt-reports__brand{
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-box-pack:justify;
    -ms-flex-pack:justify;
    justify-content:space-between;
    -ms-flex-wrap:wrap;
    flex-wrap:wrap
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__head .kt-reports__brand .kt-reports__title{
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:2.0rem;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-top:5px;
    color:#595d6e;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__head .kt-reports__brand .kt-reports__logo{
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction:normal;
    -ms-flex-direction:column;
    flex-direction:column;
    margin-top:5px;
    text-align:right
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__head .kt-reports__brand .kt-reports__logo img{
    margin-left: auto;
    height:64px;
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__head .kt-reports__brand .kt-reports__logo .kt-reports__desc{
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction:normal;
    -ms-flex-direction:column;
    flex-direction:column;
    text-align:right;
    font-weight:400;
    padding:1rem 0 1rem 0;
    color:#74788d
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__head .kt-reports__items{
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap:wrap;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    margin-top:50px;
    width:100%;
    border-top:1px solid #ebedf2
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__head .kt-reports__items .kt-reports__item{
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction:normal;
    -ms-flex-direction:column;
    flex-direction:column;
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
    -ms-flex:1;
    flex:1;
    color:#595d6e;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-top:20px
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__head .kt-reports__items .kt-reports__item:last-child{
    margin-right:0
}
.kt-reports .generated_date {
    font-size:11px;
    text-align:right;
}
.kt-reports .generated_date .subtitle {
    font-weight:500;
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__head .kt-reports__items .kt-reports__item .kt-reports__subtitle{
    font-weight:500;
    padding-bottom:.5rem
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__head .kt-reports__items .kt-reports__item .kt-reports__text{
    font-weight:400;
    color:#74788d
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body{
    padding:3rem 0
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body table{
    background-color:transparent
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body table thead tr th{
    background-color:transparent;
    padding:1rem 9px .5rem 9px;
    color:#74788d;
/*
    border-top:0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ebedf2;
 */
    border:2px solid #595d6e;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:13px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
/*.kt-reports .kt-reports__body table thead tr th:not(:first-child){
    text-align:right
}
 */
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body table tr.totals_footer td:first-child {text-align:right !important;}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body table tr.totals_footer td{
    text-align:right;
    padding: 1rem 9px 1rem 9px;
    font-weight:700;
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body .table .lrg, .kt-reports .kt-reports__body .subtable .lrg {
    width:60%;
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body .table .med, .kt-reports .kt-reports__body .subtable .med {
    width:40%;
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body .table .p30, .kt-reports .kt-reports__body .subtable .p30 {
    width:30%;
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body .table .sml, .kt-reports .kt-reports__body .subtable .sml {
    width:20%;
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body .table .vsml, .kt-reports .kt-reports__body .subtable .vsml {
    width:10%;
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body .table .tny, .kt-reports .kt-reports__body .subtable .tny {
    width:5%;
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body .table .f114, .kt-reports .kt-reports__body .subtable .f114 {
    width:114px;
    text-align:center;
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body .table .f50, .kt-reports .kt-reports__body .subtable .f50 {
    width:50px;
    text-align:center;
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body table tbody tr td{
    background-color:transparent;
    padding:1rem 9px 1rem 9px;
    border-top:none;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#595d6e
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body table thead tr td.ctal,
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body table tbody tr td.ctal,
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body table tbody tr td:first-child  {text-align:center;}

.kt-reports .kt-reports__body table.noctal tr td:first-child {text-align:initial;}

.kt-reports .kt-reports__body table thead tr td.rtal,
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body table tbody tr td.rtal {text-align:right !important;}

.kt-reports .kt-reports__body table thead tr td.ltal,
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body table tbody tr td.ltal {text-align:left;}

.kt-reports .subtable {
    width:100%;
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body table.subtable tbody tr td:first-child  {text-align:left;}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body .subtable tbody tr td {
    padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body .subtable tbody tr td:last-child {
    padding-right:0px;
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body .subtable tbody tr td.f114:last-child {
    width:104px;
    padding-right:0px;
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body .subtable tbody tr td:first-child {
    padding-left:0px;
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body table.alt_row_subdata tbody tr td{
    padding:1rem 1px 0.3rem 1px;
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body table.alt_row_subdata tbody tr:nth-child(even) td {
    padding:2px;
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:#fff;
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body .subtable tbody tr,.kt-reports .kt-reports__body .subtable tbody tr td {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
/*
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body table tbody tr td:not(:first-child){
    text-align:right
}
*/
/*
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body table tbody tr:first-child td{
    padding-top:1.8rem
}
*/
.kt-reports .kt-reports__body .subtable tbody tr:first-child td{
    padding-top:0rem
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__footer{
    padding:3rem 0;
    background-color:#f7f8fa
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__footer .kt-reports__container{
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction:normal;
    -ms-flex-direction:row;
    flex-direction:row;
    -webkit-box-pack:justify;
    -ms-flex-pack:justify;
    justify-content:space-between;
    -ms-flex-wrap:wrap;
    flex-wrap:wrap
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__footer .table{
    background-color:transparent;
    padding:0
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__footer .table th{
    font-size:1.1rem;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    font-weight:500;
    color:#74788d;
    border-top:0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ebedf2;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 0;
    background-color:transparent
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__footer .table th:last-child{
    padding-right:0
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__footer .table td{
    font-size:1.1rem;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    background-color:transparent;
    font-weight:500;
    color:#595d6e;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 0
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__footer .table td:last-child{
    padding-right:0
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__actions{
    padding:2rem 0
}
.kt-reports .kt-reports__actions .kt-reports__container{
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction:normal;
    -ms-flex-direction:row;
    flex-direction:row;
    -webkit-box-pack:justify;
    -ms-flex-pack:justify;
    justify-content:space-between
}
@media (min-width:1025px){
    .kt-reports .kt-reports__container{
        width:100%;
        margin:0 auto
    }
    .kt-reports .kt-reports__head .kt-reports__brand .kt-reports__title{
        font-weight:700;
        font-size:2rem;
        margin-bottom:30px;
        max-width:540px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:1024px) {
    .kt-reports .kt-reports__head .kt-reports__brand .kt-reports__title{
        max-width:340px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:768px){
    .kt-reports .kt-reports__container{
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0 20px
    }
    .kt-reports .kt-reports__head{
        padding:20px 0
    }
    .kt-reports .kt-reports__head .kt-reports__brand{
        display:-webkit-box;
        display:-ms-flexbox;
        display:flex;
        -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction:normal;
        -ms-flex-direction:column;
        flex-direction:column
    }
    .kt-reports .kt-reports__head .kt-reports__brand .kt-reports__title{
        font-weight:700;
        font-size:2rem;
        margin-bottom:30px;
        max-width:240px;
    }
    .kt-reports .kt-reports__head .kt-reports__brand .kt-reports__logo{
        text-align:left
    }
    .kt-reports .kt-reports__head .kt-reports__brand .kt-reports__logo img{
        text-align:left
    }
    .kt-reports .kt-reports__head .kt-reports__brand .kt-reports__logo .kt-reports__desc{
        text-align:left
    }
    .kt-reports .kt-reports__head .kt-reports__items{
        margin-top:20px
    }
    .kt-reports .kt-reports__body{
        padding:2rem 0
    }
    .kt-reports .kt-reports__footer{
        padding:2rem 0
    }
}
@media print{
/*    @page {size: landscape} */
    .kt-reports{
        border-top-left-radius:0;
        border-top-right-radius:0
    }
    .kt-reports .kt-reports__head{
        padding:45px 0 20px 0;
        border-top-left-radius:0;
        border-top-right-radius:0
    }
    .kt-reports .kt-reports__head .kt-reports__brand .kt-reports__title{
        max-width:340px;
    }
    .kt-reports .kt-reports__head .kt-reports__container{
        border-top-left-radius:0;
        border-top-right-radius:0
    }
    .kt-reports .kt-reports__body {
        padding: 1rem 0;
    }
        .kt-reports .kt-reports__actions{
        display:none!important
    }
    .kt-reports .kt-reports__footer{
        background-color:transparent!important
    }
    .kt-reports .kt-reports__container{
        width:100%;
        padding:0 10px
    }
    .kt-header {
        display:none!important;
    }
    .kt_header_mobile {
        display:none!important;
    }
    .kt-subheader {
        display:none!important;
    }
    .kt-footer {
        display:none!important;
    }
    .kt-aside {
        display:none!important;
    }
    .kt-aside__brand-logo, .kt-header-mobile__logo {
        display:none !important;
    }
    .kt-content {
        padding: 0!important;
    }
    #kt_wrapper{
        padding: 0!important;
    }
}
```

HTML Code (Laravel / Blade):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="kt-container  kt-container--fluid  kt-grid__item kt-grid__item--fluid">
        <!--begin::Portlet-->
        <div class="kt-portlet" id="report-wrapper">
            <div class="kt-portlet__body kt-portlet__body--fit">
                <div class="kt-reports">
                    <div class="kt-reports__head">
                        <div class="kt-reports__container">
                            <div class="kt-reports__brand">
                                <h1 class="kt-reports__title">{{__($report_title)}}</h1>
                                <div href="#" class="kt-reports__logo">
                                    <img src="/images/setangol.png" alt="Logo" />
                                    <span class="kt-reports__desc">
                                        <span>Postal: {{$bursary_administrator->postal_address}}</span>
                                        <span>Physical: {{$bursary_administrator->physical_address}}</span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="generated_date">
                                <span><span class="subtitle">{{__('Report Generated')}}:</span> @php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); @endphp</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="kt-reports__body">
                        <div class="kt-reports__container">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="f50">{{__('Row')}}</th>
                <th class="med">{{__('Student Full Name')}}</th>
                <th>{{__('Course')}}</th>
                <th class="f114">{{__('Registration Date')}}</th>
                <th class="f114">{{__('Subsidy USD')}}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @php($row_count=0)
        @if ($students)
            @foreach ($students as $student)
                @php($row_count++)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$row_count}}</td>
                <td>{{$student->getStudentFullNameAttribute()}}</td>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <table class="subtable">
                        <tbody>
                        @if ($student->bursaries)
                            @foreach ($student->bursaries as $bursary)
                                <tr>
                                @if ($bursary->enrolments->count()>0)
                                    @foreach ($bursary->enrolments as $enrolment)
                                        @if ($enrolment->courses->count()>0)
                                            @foreach ($enrolment->courses as $course)
                                                <td>{{$course->course}}</td>
                                            @endforeach
                                        @else
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        @endif
                                    @endforeach
                                @endif
                                    <td class="f114">{{$bursary->registration_date}}</td>
                                    <td class="rtal f114">$ {{number_format($bursary->subsidy_allowance,2,".",",")}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        @endif
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        @endif
        </tbody>
    </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="kt-reports__actions">
                        <div class="kt-reports__container">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-label-brand btn-bold" onclick="pdfprint('#report-wrapper','summary_report');">Download Report</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-brand btn-bold" onclick="window.print();">Print Report</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--end::Portlet-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally had a second look at this and got to the bottom of it.
For future reference, posting this answer.

The reason for this happening were some other layers that wouldnt show on the desktop print view. However, I switched to mobile/responsive view in chrome with the 'print' rendering and saw they were still active/visible in lower resolutions (which is what was happening with the print). I originally missed this because I was only emulating the 'print' rendering, but in full desktop view - not the lower resolution modes.

Setting these layers to `display:none!important;` did the trick under the `@media print` section of my css.